# Can I schedule a single background task to run at sometime in the future on iOS

Tags: ios

I need to queue a background task on iOS to run specifically 1 minute later, and to run only once. All I have found so far in the docs is running a periodic task. Is a single one off task possible on iOS?

Comment: Couldn't you schedule it and then cancel the schedule after it has run the 1st time?

Comment: That is a possible option I guess. The next challenge is having it run at 1 minute increments.

Comment: If you are talking about running some "background" process while your app is in the foreground then you can use a `Timer`. If you are talking about running some process while your app isn't the foreground app, then no, there is no way to schedule execution at a specific interval and certainly not every minute. This has been asked many times. You could look at `BeginBackgroundTask()` with a `Timer` it gives you about a minute of background execution so it may work for you.